# mysql select between two dates has odd behavior

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, between

I am selecting all records between NOW() and specific X day interval and came across this odd behavior that I don't understand.

I am checking 24 hours into the future and 24 hours into the past:

```
select * from table where date between NOW() and NOW() + 1 interval day; //works
select * from table where date between NOW() and NOW() - 1 interval day; //no records
```

But if I reverse the `between` call:

```
select * from table where date between NOW() + 1 interval day AND NOW(); //no records
select * from table where date between NOW() - 1 interval day AND NOW(); //works
```

Why does one call into the future work, but the same call into the past not work?...and if I reverse `between` parameters, the opposite behavior happens - does not work 24 hours into the future but does work 24 hours into the past.

======================

Adding @TimBiegeleisen explanation below here written out:

```
date = '2018-05-30' ;

select * from table where date between NOW() and NOW() + 1 interval day;
     = date >= '2018-05-30' AND 'date <= 2018-05-31'; //true
select * from table where date between NOW() and NOW() - 1 interval day; records
     = date >= '2018-05-30' AND 'date <= 2018-05-29'; //false
```

AND

```
select * from table where date between NOW() + 1 interval day AND NOW();
     = date >= '2018-05-31' AND date <= '2018-05-30' //false
select * from table where date between NOW() - 1 interval day AND NOW();
     = date >= '2018-05-29' and date <= '2018-05-30'; //true
```

Comment: Strange. All I get is a syntax error. Can we see your actual queries. :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `BETWEEN` operator is interpreted a certain way:

```
WHERE date BETWEEN a AND b
```

means this:

```
WHERE date >= a AND date <= b
```

So the following two queries are equivalent:

```
select * from table where date between NOW() and NOW() - interval 1 day;
select * from table where date >= NOW() and date <= NOW() - interval 1 day;
```

Hopefully you can see that in your second query the `WHERE` condition can never be true, because a date cannot simutaneously be greater than or equal to now *and* less than now minus one at the same time.

Comment: Is everyone using a different version of MySQL to me? The queries are equivalent in the sense that they both produce the same syntax error. !?!

Comment: @Strawberry Thanks [for the correction](http://rextester.com/ZYMYLW22568).  I guess we can't assume that anything in any OP is actually working a priori.  Maybe the OP made a typo when copying over to Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thaks @TimBiegeleisen ...i understand now.  I added your explanation in code to the OP.  I didn't realize the `BETWEEN` literally translated to `date >= value AND date<= value`

Answer (score 0):

simply put,

For SQL:
`WHERE x between a and b`
meaning

`x >= a`
and
`x <= b`

therefore, we have `a <= x <= b` or `a <= b`

PS: it's just about math :)